# Removing nested part from a SELECT query

Tags: mysql, select, nested

I'm stuck trying to remove the nested part from the following query :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `audit` WHERE action_performed = 'REJECTED' AND `event_id` IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT event_id AS `Count` 
        FROM `audit` 
        WHERE username = 'someUser' 
        AND action_performed IN ('SUBMITTED_FOR_APPROVAL', 'SAVED_AND_APPROVED')
        AND (action_timestamp >= '2012-01-12 00:00:00' AND action_timestamp <= '2012-01-24 23:59:59'))
```

Basically, I'm trying to fetch the number of rejected events by a user, that were submitted by him before. I determine this by the `action_performed` column which takes values such as
`SUBMITTED_FOR_APPROVAL`, `SAVED_AND_APPROVED` and `REJECTED`.

The reason I want to remove the nested part is because the `audit` table currently contains over 100k rows, and the result of the nested query itself is around 2000 rows, so the query always times out.

I've tried searching on the site, and doing an INNER JOIN as suggested in some questions, but maybe I was doing it wrong!
Thank you.

EDIT - The `audit` table structure is as follows

```
Field              Type   
id                 int(11)
username           varchar(100)
event_id           int(11)
action_performed   varchar(100) 
action_timestamp   timestamp
```

Comment: @OcasoProtal - This is the query that I tried, which gave no results
`SELECT DISTINCT a.event_id FROM audit a
INNER JOIN audit a2
ON a.id = a2.id
WHERE (a.action_performed = 'REJECTED')
AND a2.action_performed IN ('SUBMITTED_FOR_APPROVAL', 'SAVED_AND_APPROVED')
AND a.username = 'someUser' 
AND (a.action_timestamp >= '2012-01-12 00:00:00' AND a.action_timestamp <= '2012-01-24 23:59:59')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT adata.*
FROM  `audit` AS adata
INNER JOIN `audit` AS aselector ON adata.event_id=aselector.event_id
WHERE
  adata.action_performed = 'REJECTED'
  AND aselector.username = 'someUser' 
  AND aselector.action_performed IN ('SUBMITTED_FOR_APPROVAL', 'SAVED_AND_APPROVED')
  AND aselector.action_timestamp >= '2012-01-12 00:00:00'
  AND aselector.action_timestamp <= '2012-01-24 23:59:59'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the query that you tried you linked tables with `id` field (`ON a.id = a2.id`) but in the first query they are linked with `event_id`. That seems to be a problem, so try `ON a.event_id = a2.event_id`.

Comment: I tried it according to your comment, but still got an empty result set. There definitely are a few rows though, since the first query in the question returns them (I deleted some data from the `audit` table to fix this problem).

Comment: Okay, two more things: `a.action_timestamp` and `a.username`. You should use `a2` table for these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT AuditTable.event_id, ... -- add other fields here
FROM  `audit` AS AuditTable
INNER JOIN `audit` AS AuditTableB ON AuditTable.event_id=aselector.event_id
WHERE
    AuditTable.action_performed = 'REJECTED'
    AND AuditTableB.username = 'someUser' 
    AND AuditTableB.action_performed IN ('SUBMITTED_FOR_APPROVAL', 'SAVED_AND_APPROVED')
    AND (AuditTableB.action_timestamp BETWEEN '2012-01-12 00:00:00' AND  '2012-01-24 23:59:59')
```